# how to edit back button push style transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I create two page VC that has tableView and push style transition together.

I want custom back button push style transition that when return pervious page this page reload again and receive data again.

Comment: You cannot edit that transition. What do you want to achieve? may be there is some other way

Comment: I think this is not the place to "tell me more about it".Please make your question clear such that it can have a definite answer

Answer (score 0):

If a custom transition is what you need you can start off with:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom forView:[[self navigationController] view] cache:YES];

[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button on the navigation bar that replaces the backbutton with `hidesBackButton` set to `YES` and then just make it perform a custom segue.